# Should I add $\frac {4 \pi}{3}\delta^3(\vec x) \mathbf{I}$ or $4 \pi \delta^3(\vec x) \hat x \hat x$ to the gradient of $\frac{\vec x}{x^3}$?

Tags: tensors, singularity

I know that divergence of $\frac{\vec x}{x^3}$ is $4 \pi\delta^3(\vec x)$ and also that trace of gradient of a vector is its divergence.

When I take the gradient of $\frac{\vec x}{x^3}$ I get:
$$\nabla\frac{\vec x}{x^3} = \frac{\mathbf I}{x^3} -3 \frac {\vec x \vec x}{x^5}$$

Which is traceless. So should I add $\frac {4 \pi}{3}\delta^3(\vec x) \mathbf{I}$ to the gradient?

**Update:** $4 \pi \delta^3(\vec x) \hat x \hat x$ also gives the correct trace. So it's more complicated now.

Comment: Probably it's better to proceed by using the divergence theorem here, since that lets you directly measure any contribution from a delta-function.

Comment: What's the gradient of a vector?

Comment: @snulty why would a mathematical physics phd ask that?

Comment: @azad I missed the part where it said you were dealing with tensors, which is only in the tags... I was thinking gradient of a scalar, div and curl of vectors.

Comment: @snulty It's okay. I regularly encounter these in fluid dynamics (eg Oseen tensors) and we even have to take gradient of the Oseen tensor to get flow field of the stokeslet.

Comment: @Azad tbh I prefer to use tensor index notation $\nabla_\mu(\frac{x^\nu}{|x|^3})=\frac{\delta_\mu^\nu}{|x^3|}-3\frac{x_\mu x^\nu}{|x|^5}$. Bear in mind though that this expression is traceless only for $\vec{x}\neq \vec{0}$ as it's not defined there. I think by the same reason you know that the divergence is $4\pi\delta^3(\vec{x})$, the trace of this is also $4\pi\delta^3(\vec{x})$.